# Pré-vizualizacao de informações ao selecionar campo no input

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho uma duvida, na verdade não sei se é possível, já que eu procurei na net e não achei nada.

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer pre-visualização de um "perfil" ao selecionar o nome desse perfil em um `<Option>`

Tipo

```
<select id="selecao">
        <option value="perfil 1">Fulano</option>
        <option value="perfil 2">Fulanin</option>
        <option value="perfil 2">Ciclano</option>
</select>
```

Ai após selecionar um dos nomes citados na lista abrir uma especie de mini-card com mais informações daquele usuário

Comment: você quer fazer isso ao selecionar o *option* ou ao passar o mouse por cima?

Comment: ao selecionar..

Comment: Onde ficam armazenadas as informações dos perfis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim é possível. Se a informação estiver do lado do servidor vai precisar de `ajax` e no `select` vai precisar de escutar o evento `change`.

O ajax é uma ferramenta/método para comunicar entre o browser e o servidor. Você pode passar informação para o servidor e o ajax fica à espera da resposta e corre uma função quando a receber.

Para despoletar o ajax precisa de um event handler. Um escutador que detecta quando o select muda, quando faz uma escolha. Aí, dentro dessa função pode fazer o pedido ajax.

Por exemplo:

```
$('#selecao').on('change', function(){
     var data = { opcao: $(this).val()};
     $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        data: data,     
        success: function(respostaServidor){                          
            $("#resposta").html(respostaServidor); // mero exemplo                  
        }           
    });   
});
```

Depois precisa do lado do servidor escutar este pedido com por exemplo (assumindo que PHP é a linguagem do lado do servidor):

```
$opcao = $_GET["opcao"]; // guardar os dados do ajax numa variável

// depois precisa de fazer uma query à base de dados, 
// aqui varia conforme o que tem no servidor e precisa precisar melhor na pergunta
// Depois da query à base de dados (ou ficheiro) pode retornar o valor com por exemplo:

echo $dados; // enviar resposta de volta para o lado do cliente
```

Comment: Droga, cancelei a resposta de novo. kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk. tome um `+1`

Comment: @ErlonCharles, sorry :P Na próxima espero mais 10 segundos a ver se você está por perto :)

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk